# Random forest for feature selection over large inhomogeneous data set

Tags: python, random-forest, feature-selection, scikit-learn

I have a very large dataset (500,000 examples, 3000 features with a lot of missing values). I want to run a random forest algorithm for feature selection with sklearn. Unfortunately, I cannot load the entire dataset. Is it possible to run random forest over chunks of the dataset? What other options do I have?

Thanks in advance